# How to locate gc/memory problems from spark.log

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I write code which read from a big table and use many `withColumn` to modify columns. I deploy the application as cluster mode on yarn, and it stops when finished one stage, and computation for the next stage never starts.

After doing some [reading](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015), I understand that when I use lots of `withColumn`, there will be a huge memory problem, so I checked the driver's gc.log, and it shows

```
2019-11-26T17:31:51.105+0800: 537.017: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 3034528K->239328K(3514368K)] 18929536K->16368376K(20291584K), 0.3332585 secs] [Times: user=1.05 sys=0.24, real=0.33 secs] 
2019-11-26T17:31:51.438+0800: 537.350: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 239328K->0K(3514368K)] [ParOldGen: 16129048K->15788587K(16777216K)] 16368376K->15788587K(20291584K), [Metaspace: 98385K->98385K(100352K)], 102.4043873 secs] [Times: user=398.46 sys=4.14, real=102.41 secs] 
2019-11-26T17:33:47.348+0800: 653.260: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2824192K->241022K(3504128K)] 18612779K->16029609K(20281344K), 0.2878782 secs] [Times: user=0.79 sys=0.31, real=0.29 secs]
```

Obviously, the memory exceeds, and a Full GC happens which cost 102 seconds. When I replace `withColumn` with `createDataFrame`, my application runs smoothly.

Though the probelm is identified and solved, I want to locate the problem more precisely, so next time when someone encounter this problem again, I can identify it from some pattern in spark.log and gc.log, without access to his/her source code. However when I checked spark.log, I can't find anything direct linked to memory allocation problems.

```
19/11/26 17:31:43 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlA: closed
19/11/26 17:31:43 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlA: stopped, remaining connections 1
19/11/26 17:31:45 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: Number of pending allocations is 0. Slept for 3000/3000.
19/11/26 17:31:45 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: Sending progress
19/11/26 17:31:45 DEBUG YarnAllocator: Updating resource requests, target: 1, pending: 0, running: 1, executorsStarting: 0
19/11/26 17:31:45 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 148: Call -&gt; urlB: allocate {blacklist_request { } response_id: 218 progress: 0.1}
19/11/26 17:31:45 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlB sending #646
19/11/26 17:31:45 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlB got value #646
19/11/26 17:31:45 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: allocate took 1ms
19/11/26 17:31:45 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 148: Response &lt;- urlB: allocate {response_id: 219 limit { } num_cluster_nodes: 960 preempt { strictContract { } }}
19/11/26 17:31:48 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: Number of pending allocations is 0. Slept for 3000/3000.
19/11/26 17:31:48 DEBUG ApplicationMaster: Sending progress
19/11/26 17:31:48 DEBUG YarnAllocator: Updating resource requests, target: 1, pending: 0, running: 1, executorsStarting: 0
19/11/26 17:31:48 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 148: Call -&gt; urlB: allocate {blacklist_request { } response_id: 219 progress: 0.1}
19/11/26 17:31:48 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlB sending #647
19/11/26 17:31:48 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlB got value #647
19/11/26 17:31:48 DEBUG ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: allocate took 1ms
19/11/26 17:31:48 TRACE ProtobufRpcEngine: 148: Response &lt;- urlB: allocate {response_id: 220 limit { } num_cluster_nodes: 960 preempt { strictContract { } }}
19/11/26 17:33:33 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlB : closed
19/11/26 17:33:33 DEBUG DFSClient: DataStreamer block BlockA sending packet packet seqno:-1 offsetInBlock:0 lastPacketInBlock:false lastByteOffsetInBlock: 0
19/11/26 17:33:33 DEBUG Client: IPC Client (xxx) connection to urlB : stopped, remaining connections 0
```

My question is if I find a gc problem in my driver's gc.log, can I locate the problem more precisely  using spark.log.